# memcache connections reaching its limit...?

Tags: php, memcached

I recently launched my project and had around 2000+ users accessing the application within 10 minutes. I have setup memcache to handle the sessions. What happened was that the server went very slow, almost to an unbearable level. I closed down the website because of this to investigate the cause. Is it possible that it is related to memcache connections? A limitation of them?

Note that I am not experienced with memcache so please be thorough with any assitance.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the solution on this question:
[memcached and PHP ... massive lag with sessions](https://serverfault.com/questions/148266/memcached-and-php-massive-lag-with-sessions)

You might also make sure you gave memcached enough RAM, the default on most distro's in only 64mb.  Is that enough to hold all of the session data for all 2000 users.

Mark